# Python: Does finally needs a try-except clause?

Tags: python, except, finally

Suppose the following code.

```
try:
    some_code_1
except: # will it be called twice, if an error occures in finally?
    some_code_2
finally:
    some_code_3
```

Suppose an exception occurs in `some_code_3`. Do I need an extra try-except clause around `some_code_3` (see below) or will the exception with `some_code_2` be called again, which in principle could cause an infinite loop?

Is this saver?

```
try:
    some_code_1
except: # will it be called twice, if an error occures in finally?
    some_code_2
finally:
    try:
        some_code_3
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Please [don't tag in title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586041/how-to-catch-error-in-finally-block-in-python). Why don't you [try it](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6So0oqLsygxszhVwbUiObWgJDM/T0MpM08BKKOQlJOfnK2kyZUKlgEqLCjKzCvRUIKrVEhOLE3PKAEqScvMS8zJwWUYVBZm4P//AA)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give it a try:

```
try:
    print(abc) #Will raise NameError
except: 
    print("In exception")
finally:
    print(xyz) #Will raise NameError

Output: 
In exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/test/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(xyz)
NameError: name 'xyz' is not defined
```

So no, it doesn't end up in an infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

python doesn't go back in the execution flow, but rather statement by statement.

By the time it reaches `finally`, if an error is thrown there, it needs yet another handle

Answer (score 2):

The **finally** in your sample code will not catch exception from some_code_3.

whether it's needed to catch exception from some_code_3 depends on your design.